# unrecognized command: "vob_restore"

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

We've recently been forced into rebuilding a ClearCase 8.0.0.5 server and restoring VOB snapshots.  After installing CC and seemingly getting it up and running, I'm running into issues when I attempt to run vob_restore.

```
C:\>cleartool
cleartool> vob_restore
cleartool: Error: Unrecognized command: "vob_restore"
```

Although it's been a while since I've done this, but I've never had this issue before.

Could anyone help point me in a direction that would explain why this is "missing" and to get it up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`vob_restore` (man page)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/vob_restore.htm) is *not* a `cleartool` command:

Example: to restore VOB /vobs/src on a UNIX or Linux system

```
/opt/rational/clearcase/etc/vob_restore /vobs/src
```

See more in "[Running `vob_restore`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_restore_vob_restore.htm)".

Comment: Thank you, VonC.  I had run across the second link you provided and inadvertently made a mental connection between the use of cleartool in Step 2 with the use of vob_restore bat in Step 3.  Like I said, it's been a while since I've done this. :)